Apache WSGI module Fails to Start with net start apache2.4, but Works with httpd.exe
I’m currently facing an issue with my Apache server setup on Windows. I’ve been able to run Apache successfully using httpd.exe, but when I attempt to start it using net start apache2.4, the service fails to start, and I receive an error in the Event Viewer (no corresponding Apache error log though)
System Details

Apache Version: Apache 2.4 (64-bit)
Python Version: Python 3.13
mod_wsgi Version: 5.0.1 (64-bit)
Django App Path: C:/webapp
WSGI Module Path: C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp313-win_amd64.pyd

What I’ve Tried
1. Running httpd.exe Directly:

Apache starts successfully and serves my Django application as expected.
No issues with the Django app or the WSGI module when starting manually.

**2. Running httpd -t **

Returns Syntax OK.

3. Windows Event Viewer Error:

When starting Apache with net start apache2.4, I see the following error in the Event Viewer:

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 194 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp313-win_amd64.pyd 
into server: The specified module could not be found.     .

4. Verified File Paths:

I have confirmed that the mod_wsgi file exists in the exact location specified in the httpd.conf file:

c:\Apache24\bin>dir "C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server"
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8205-BA06
 Directory of C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server

10/23/2024  02:49 PM    <DIR>          .
10/23/2024  02:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/23/2024  02:49 PM             1,097 apxs_config.py
10/23/2024  02:49 PM             3,563 environ.py
10/23/2024  02:49 PM    <DIR>          management
10/23/2024  02:49 PM           134,656 mod_wsgi.cp313-win_amd64.pyd
10/23/2024  02:49 PM           138,014 __init__.py
10/23/2024  02:49 PM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               4 File(s)        277,330 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  56,747,614,208 bytes free

What’s Confusing

Apache runs fine using httpd.exe, but it fails when using net start apache2.4.
No error is being logged in the Apache logs (either the error log or the access log).
The mod_wsgi module seems to load without issue when running manually, but not as a service.

Configuration

httpd.conf (mod_wsgi load):

LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp313-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/{my_webapp}"


VirtualHost configuration:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName .com
    ServerAlias www.{my_webapp}.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/{my_webapp}"

    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/{my_webapp}/{my_webapp}/wsgi.py
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    LogLevel info wsgi:debug

    <Directory C:/{my_webapp}/{my_webapp}>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ C:/{my_webapp}/static/
    <Directory C:/{my_webapp}/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "C:/Apache24/logs/{my_webapp}_error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Apache24/logs/{my_webapp}_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Steps Taken So Far

Verified that Apache and mod_wsgi are both 64-bit.
Confirmed that the paths to Python and mod_wsgi are correct.
Ran httpd.exe successfully, confirming the setup works manually.
Checked Windows Event Viewer for errors but didn’t see any additional details logged in the Apache error log.

My Question
Why is Apache able to run via httpd.exe but fails when using net start apache2.4? How can I troubleshoot this further, especially considering the lack of logs in Apache?
Relevant Posts

mod_wsgi not found for apache/windows
https://serverfault.com/questions/1070563/why-is-apache2-not-finding-my-wsgi-app
https://groups.google.com/g/modwsgi/c/RVD1hIxb2eI

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

per the last link in the relevant posts.
run mod_wsgi-express module-config
replace what i had in my httpd.conf to load with the output:
LoadFile "C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python313.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp313-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/{me}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313"

